# How many times will the while loop be executed?

Tags: python, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, addition

I am wondering about how many times this while loop would execute. This is a function that adds two numbers using XOR and AND.

```
def Add(x, y): 

    # Iterate till there is no carry  
    while (y != 0): 

        # carry now contains common 
        # set bits of x and y 
        carry = x & y 

        # Sum of bits of x and y where at 
        # least one of the bits is not set 
        x = x ^ y 

        # Carry is shifted by one so that    
        # adding it to x gives the required sum 
        y = carry << 1

    return x 
``
```

Comment: add a counter,initialize it before the loop, add 1 inside the loop, print/return value together with x? where is your problem?

Comment: he wants to know how many times it executes depending on the inputs.

Comment: def Add(x, y):
        counter = 0
        # Iterate till there is no carry
        while (y != 0):
    
            counter +=1
    
            # carry now contains common
            # set bits of x and y
            carry = x & y
    
            # Sum of bits of x and y where at
            # least one of the bits is not set
            x = x ^ y
    
            # Carry is shifted by one so that
            # adding it to x gives the required sum
            y = carry << 1
    
        print(counter)
        return x
    
    
    Add(3,5)

Comment: If we have values like this: y=100010 and x = 0 then according to you there should be 0 iteration but there is one iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm for **No Carry Adder**:

```
function no_carry_adder(A,B)
    while B != 0:
        X = A XOR B, Bitwise-XOR of A,B.
        Y = A AND B, Bitwise-AND of A,B.
        A = X
        B = Y << 1, Multiplying Y by 2.
    return A
```

As you can see, the `while` loop executes those four instructions again and again until `B = 0`, and when `B = 0`, binary number stored in `A` is the answer.
Now the question was to find out how many times the `while` loop will execute before `B = 0` or `B` becomes zero.

If I have gone for the naive way i.e write the algorithm as it is described in any programming language like it will give me an answer but it will be time-consuming if the number of bits in the binary string `A` and `B` is `> 500`.

**How can I make a faster algorithm?** 
Let's take a look at different cases,

- **Case 1:** When both `A = B = 0`.
         In this case the number of times the loop iterates `= 0` as `B = 0`.
- **Case 2:** When `A != 0` and `B = 0`.
         In this case also the number of times the loop iterates `= 0` as `B = 0`.
- **Case 3:** When `A = 0` and `B != 0`.
         In this case, the number of times the loop iterates `= 1` because after the first iteration, the value of `X = B` as when you do the `bitwise XOR` of any binary number with `0` the result is the number itself. The value of `Y = 0` because `bitwise AND` of any number with `0` is `0`. So, you can see `Y = 0` then `B = 0` and `Y << 1 = 0`.
- **Case 4:** When `A = B` and `A != 0` and `B != 0`.
         In this case, the number of times the loop iterates `= 2` because in first iteration the value of `A = 0`, why because `bitwise XOR` of two same numbers is always `0` and value of `Y = B` because `bitwise AND` of two same numbers is the number itself and then `B = Y << 1`, after the first iteration, `A = 0`  and `B != 0` so this case becomes **Case-3**. So, the number of iteration will always be `2`.
- **Case-5:** When `A != B` and `A != 0` and `B != 0`.
  In this case, the number of times the loop iterates `= length of the longest carry-chain`.

**Algorithm to calculate the length of the longest carry-chain:**

- First make both the binary strings `A` and `B` of equal length if they are not.
- As we know the length of the largest carry sequence will be the answer, I just need to find the maximum carry sequence length I have occurred till now. So, to compute that,
- I will iterate from left to right i.e. LSB to MSB and:

  - `if carry + A[i] + B[i] == 2` means that bit marks the start of carry-sequence, so `++curr_carry_sequence` and `carry = 1`.
  - `if carry + A[i] + B[i] == 3` means the carry which was forwarded by previous bit addition is consumed here and this bit will generate a new carry so, length of carry-sequence will reset to 1 i.e. `curr_carry_sequence = 1` and `carry = 1`.
  - `if carry + A[i] + B[i] == 1 or 0` means carry generated by the previous bit resolves here and it will mark the end of the carry-sequence, so the length of the carry-sequence will reset to 0. i.e. `curr_carry_sequence = 0` and `carry = 0`.
- Now if `curr_carry_seq` length is `>` than `max_carry_sequence`, then you update the `max_carry_sequence`.
- Answer would be `max_carry_sequence + 1`.

For Source-code refer to [No Carry Adder Solution](https://github.com/strikersps/Competitive-Programming/tree/master/Code-Chef/Addition).

P.S. For average-case analysis of **No-Carry Adder** you can refer to the paper: [Average Case Analysis of No Carry Adder: Addition in `log(n) + O(1)`Steps on Average: A Simple Analysis](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p_iqOh9B_fmloV-TC6sGaR0diEm4qvl0/view?usp=drivesdk).

Answer (score 2):

There is no fixed answer to how many times the while loop is executed. The while loop is always executed when there is a carry bit from one position to another. Hence you need to know how exactly the numbers look like in binary.  But what you can say with certainty is what the max possible number of executions is. It is the length of the bigger number as bits + 1. Why? Because if that's the number that a carry can max occur. Let's take add(1,7) = 8 (001 + 111 = 1000). The carry from the first bit is passed two the second position then to the third and then to the forth. 4 iterations this is equivalent to the length of 7 and that + 1 = 4.

Comment: If we knew exactly how the numbers in binary look, how would you calculate how many times the while loop ran without actually running it?

Comment: The problem for calculating the executions is that in one iteration many carries can be added at once e.g 5+5 (101 + 101) needs two iterations first get all carries and then add them. In this case, the carries can both be added and won't produce a new carry. On the other hand, if we look at 3+1 (11+1) we need 3 iterations even when we only have two carriers. The second iteration will produce a new carry. So one more iteration. You need to look how many values are influenced by one others carry and subtract the once wich you can add simultaneously. So the easiest way is to do the algorithm.

Comment: If we have values like this: y=100010 and x = 0 then according to you there should be 0 iteration but there is one iteration